# Google Earth Engine: How to use a shape file as area of interest during calculation of NDVI with Cloud masking and land masking

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate the annual  NDVI with Cloud masking and land masking for Australia.

I am getting this error

Image (Error)
reduce.mean: Error in map(ID=0): Image.bitwiseAnd: Bitwise operands must be integer only.

my code is
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftafzilamouly%2Ffpc%3AEXPLORE

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an external website, could you include your code in the post itself?

Comment: I have updated my question in the answer section. Please help

Comment: @TafzilaMouly, the link to your code does not work. To share your code, just click the `Get Link` button on the left of the `Save` button.